# Join between android table and own Sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a sqlite tables for save some id songs.

My first table is for name lists.

```
String SENTENCE_CREATE_TABLE_LISTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LISTS
        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + LIS_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + LIS_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'List');";
```

My second table is for relation between id list and id song.

```
String SENTENCE_CREATE_TABLE_LIST_SONGS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LIST_SONG
        + " (" + CAN_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + LIS_ID + " INTENGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);";
```

Now, I need the song info from android table for music called by URI `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

How I can make a JOIN between this tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins are possible only between tables in the same database, or with tables in [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)ed databases.

In Android, you do not get direct access to the system's database files, so this is not possible.

You have to read the data through the appropriate content provider, and do the join with your own data manually.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that but I wanted to be sure.